# Audio transcription

Tags: audio, software-recommendation

Trying to help a friend record and transcribe her experiences. She is not able to write for long periods due to vision issues. Considered voice recorder but need it to be simple with easy to read functions and then must be able to connect to her first generation iPad to transcribe and organize.

Other options or ideas?

Comment: What version of iOS is running? What apps have you seen on the App Store that do or don't work. See [meta] for tips on asking for software recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the iPad's "[Speech to Text](http://atsupportocsb.weebly.com/setting-up-the-speech-to-text-feature-ipad-3-or-4-only.html)" function - maybe not available with a first generation iPad? If it is an option, I am pretty sure the iPad needs an active internet for this function to work

[image]

I don't know why the iPad doesn't come with the Voice Memo app like iPhone, but the free app [Audio Memos Free - The Voice Recorder](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audio-memos-free-voice-recorder/id304075033?mt=8) might do the job of recording audio for you directly on the iPad. I don't know that she can listen and type at the same time, tho.